# Does a Code-Signed application require security permissions?

Tags: macos, security, code-signing

I am contemplating whether to purchase a Personal Apple CodeSign certificate, for 99$/year. I have a medium-sized user base, and an app that is installed multiple times a month by each user. Upon installation, the user is required to allow 6 permissions in their Security Settings, for the app to function properly.

If I am to code-sign my app with an Apple certificate, would this eliminate the need for my users to perform this lengthy step each time they install the app? If not, what other approach can I take to eliminate this installation step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions granted in the "Security & Privacy" preference pane are not related to code signing per se. These are runtime permissions that user can grant or revoke, and the app would still continue to be able to run (your app should react to the corresponding errors of the APIs related to these permissions, of course).

Usually, you only have to give these permissions once. An *update* should not reset them (that is: the bundle identifier must stay the same). At least that's the way it works with App Store, Ad Hoc, and Developer ID signed apps. I'm not entirely sure whether it's true for completely unsigned apps, though.

So as long as the bundler identifier stays the same and the app is updated by replacing it in its previous location, the permissions should not need to be granted anew.